# How to implement synchronous functions in typescript (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, function, synchronous, sequential

I have a function that I want to run sequentially/synchronously, but my function is running asynchronously. I don't know how to make this synchronous. Here is the structure of the function.

```js
let paymentStatus: boolean = false;
console.log('action 1');

if (paymentDetails != null) {
    console.log('action 2');

    var x = (window as any).getpaidSetup({
        callback: async (response) => {
            console.log('action 3');

            if (response != null) {
                console.log('action 4');
                paymentStatus = true;

            } else {
                console.log('still action 4');
            }
            console.log('action 5');
        }
    });

    console.log('action 6');
    return paymentStatus;
}
```

I want to perform "action 1, action 2, action 3, action 4, action 5 and action 6" before returning "paymentStatus", but the system is performing thus: "action 1, action 2, action 6, return operation, action 3, action 4, action 5". I've tried to use async and await, but to no avail.

Comment: I suggest you use rxjs operators instead of convert async calls to Promise and use await. It's more "fluid and elegant" use a simple subscription. NOTE: the rxjs operators you need are forkJoin and switchMap. Convert to Promise and use await is an "ugly work-around"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `async await`, but you first have to wrap your asynchronous part into a promise. That would look something like this:

```
async function executeSequentially(paymentDetails) {
    let paymentStatus: boolean = false;
    console.log('action 1');

    if(paymentDetails != null) {        
        console.log('action 2');

        // Wrap the part that is asynchronous and await the promise
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            (window as any).getpaidSetup({           
                callback: response => {  
                    console.log('action 3');
                    
                    if (response != null){   
                        console.log('action 4');
                        paymentStatus = true;

                    }else { 
                        console.log('still action 4');
                    }
                    console.log('action 5');
                    resolve(); // resolve the Promise when async execution finished
                }
            });
        });
    }

    console.log('action 6');

    return paymentStatus;
}
```

And with a little bit of code cleanup, it could look something like this:

```
// extract promisification into its own function (no need for async, you return a promise anyway)
function promisifiedGetPaidSetup():Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
        (window as any).getpaidSetup({           
            // resolve with a boolean value, cleaner design since you don't set a variable outside
            callback: response => resolve(response != null) 
        })
    );
}

async function executeSequentially(paymentDetails):Promise<boolean> {
    // Either return the result from the promise, or false if payment details are not present
    return paymentDetails ? await promisifiedGetPaidSetup() : false;
}
```

Here a link to the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkHsGMGsGdQCIDmBTALgBwIYEsATAZUwFcslRIA7UAdz2oMjtB0Tw1D0Wsi6wAnNPDTUujUFgA2OAJ4pBkUkwB0oAMI5p0xNG3SARjjjdaARkQMMACzag%201ALTVSOqoYBWAKAAUDJhY2RBxqOQBKVXRsfGIyLFAAXlAAMxVoDDwaUF9cQRwAWwB5LwAuUABvfR1jOHLfYXgsGlFS0IikgD42MIBfcMrvUGHQUQwAFTwCtGUMX18BxO68wpLPVWqjE1hfCv6AGlBzAAZTgYBub17vbzTqDKzaIUgCnjwUvDQCAHFMAAVYiQMOQFqU-kpXqIADyGSCQaRoULdCpDEbCYGCWjUNCscEvHhoBoieEANzQXVRIxG-kYzFY7B6ESimFwhCBIIqVK5w0p3JGm1qsHqjWa1Fa7UW3UapMJIpa5IAhMlXDoBryqf1eeErjd2HJ7ql0plsmgAB5oaCkDBoEgAR1IYkyBjkuXk03EABFMPhdOUJYMqejSJipG7HV6MD7EAB%20Nh0fACCFvD5fX4YAFs%20ILUDlFLaUSXa7eECaUIAci4pFEwX10DjCdANjQwkO8EY0HJGEgCQRZOkPQIbAIBEYKFAZuagi4e1AXdABRwsE7Nh49gKkAIbnJhmEi8QtnJ6Gx%20Wtg88OBJ7GggjwWAw6gAqm3qGPVAfaIx4NacARvGaLVaNpoPajp4M6vgqtIkTvr40AtPCaCqNIkAoOE5ygCWea6Gghw4Ck1qCKAxyjBaf7mpa1p2g64hgToLp7NBTbULB8EIkhKFoRhYAYIIDq4fhzZHCR0DeEAA) with the second example "in action". It is important to note that your code will still be asynchronous (that's why it returns a promise now, which are asynchronous by nature). But the statements inside will be executed in order. So wherever you use the `executeSequentially` function, you will have to await it if you want to run it pseudo-synchronously.

Answer (score -2):

There are several solutions for these but the simpler one is to create a promises' array and use Promise.all that await till all the array promises are resolved. So the code should be like below.

```
executeSequentially(paymentDetails){
let paymentStatus: boolean = false;
let promises = []
promises.push(console.log('action 1'));

if(paymentDetails != null){        
   promises.push(console.log('action 2'));

` `var x = (window as any).getpaidSetup({           
  callback: async (response) => {  
    promises.push(console.log('action 3'));
      
      if (response != null){   
        promises.push(console.log('action 4'));
        paymentStatus = true;

      }else { 
        promises.push(console.log('still action 4'));
      }
      promises.push(console.log('action 5'));
  }
}
);

promises.push(console.log('action 6'));

await Promise.all(promises)

return paymentStatus;

}
```

Comment: your answer does not work for me. The flow is still the same

Comment: Try removing the async keyword from the callback function: remove 'callback: async (response) =>' adnd substitute for 'callback: (response) =>'

Comment: This answer only runs the `console.log` in parallel at the end... Pretty sure that is not what he wants. Removing the `async` keyword from the callback makes the callback return `void` instead of `Promise<void>` - which changes exactly nothing.